# Copy-Item to wildcard folder

Tags: powershell

I need to copy file from 1 PC to another but folders are randomly generated by software, e.g. `hsfhsrh.default`, `43642523.default` etc.

I was trying to use wildcard in `Copy-Item` and replaced `hsfhsrh.default` with `*.default` but it's not working:

```
Copy-Item \\PC1\test\*.default\test.txt -destination \\PC2\test\*.default\test.txt -recurse -Force
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Testing on local PC now... 
ERROR: Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
copyFF.ps1 (1, 10): ERROR: At Line: 1 char: 10
ERROR: + Copy-Item <<<<  C:\test\ *.default\test.txt -destination e:\test\ *.default -recurse -Force

I had ti add space after c:\test\ for comment to display correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in the destination path, as that would be ambiguous. (Should the cmdlet copy to all matching destinations? Just the first one? The last one?)

Enumerate folders in the destination share that match your pattern, select the first result and use that as your destination path:

```
$dst = Get-ChildItem \\PC2\test -Filter *.default |
       Select-Object -First 1 -Expand FullName

Copy-Item \\PC1\test\*.default\test.txt -Destination $dst -Force
```

Comment: Yes, this what I needed and it is working for me thanks @Ansgar Wiechers. 

Just quick off topic, what if the random folder is in a middle e.g. \\PC2\test\*.default\new_folder\

Comment: Doesn't work the same way. You'd have to list the shares, e.g. with `net view`, and pick the one matching your pattern. If the shares are hidden you must know the name of the share.